# K&R 1-19 // About adjusting the value of numerical counters

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

This is a very peculiar doubt about an exercise form the K&R textbook, I don't have any idea what the "standard" answer is, so the program itself may be a bit unfamiliar.

I tried to describe in the code the incremental steps that brought this program together, my question is about an adjustment that by logic shouldn't have any impact but taking away a stray `--i`.

Instead, if I try it all kind of strange behaviours appear (I tried a few combinations so I won't go to the extent of desribing them all here.. )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCHAR 15
int storeline(char line[], int lim);
void reverse(char in[], char out[], int len);
main() {
    int l;
    char line[MAXCHAR+2]; /*I add two position to accomodate a newline and a '\0' character */
    char enil[MAXCHAR+2];
    while ((l=storeline(line, MAXCHAR+2))>=0) {
        if (l<MAXCHAR)
            reverse(line, enil, l); /*reverse is called with the array (in this case a 17 characters array) and the count computed in storeline (up to )*/
        else
            reverse(line, enil, MAXCHAR);
        printf("%s", enil); 
    }
    return 0;
}

int storeline(char s[], int lim) {
    int i;
    int c;
    for(i=0;i<lim-2&&(c=getchar())!='\n'&&c!=EOF;++i){ /* this loop breaks at i==15 */
        if (c==' '||c=='\t') {
            while((c=getchar())==' '||c=='\t');
            s[i]=' ';
            ++i;
            if(c==EOF)
                break;
        }
        s[i]=c;
    }
    if (c!=EOF) {
        s[i]='\n'; /* a newline is added in s[15] */
        ++i;
    }
    s[i]='\0'; /* a '\0' character is added at s[16] */
    --i; /*no more characters have to be added so I bring the count of the characters down by 1 (a further unit is deducted by the fact that one character is stored in s[0] */
    while (c!='\n' && c!= EOF) {
        c=getchar();
        i++;
    }
    return i; /* the count goes on and is subsequently returned by the function, newline is assumed to be a file break by design, but this is easily adjusted */
}

/* let's pretend the string was '123451234512345' and MAXCHAR is 15. */
void reverse (char in[], char out[], int len) {
    int i, lim;
    i=0;
    lim=len-1; /*len was 15, now it is 14. note that the array goes up to in[16] */
    while(lim>=0) {
        out[i]=in[lim];
        ++i;
        --lim;
    }
    out[i]='\n';
    ++i;
    out[i]='\0';
}
```

My doubt is, if I remove the `--i` element in `storeline` and decrease `lim` to `len-2` everything should work as before, but it doesn't/ Why? The numbers are literally the same..

Comment: Note: `c` may be undefined in `if (c!=EOF)` when `lim <= 2`.

Comment: Gaah, a loop containing `getchar()` that contains conditional calls to `getchar()` ... That's just not the best way to do this. Read one character per iteration.

Comment: Did you try stepping through with a debugger? (Or simply adding some print statements to trace execution.)

Comment: @chux if I understand what you meant, I'll just assume that lim is never set to less then 2 (because of how the whole thing works)

Comment: @unwind yeah, it desn't look good, but that's effective as it is meant to discard characters (so that the output will not have more then one blank space betwenn words, and tabs are reduced to a blank space)

Comment: @Oliver I didn't try a debugger (I just write out of Notepad++), but I printed from a dozen different positions without coming to much result...

Comment: In it's current state, this question does not belong on Code Review. Code Review is not for understanding why something happens. But if/when this code works as expected, feel free to come by and we can help you clean up the code!

Comment: I forgot to mention the objective of the exercise: "take a line at a time and rewrite it backwards if the character count exceed a certain value, while reducing multiple blanks or tabs to one single blank space". Actually, the exercise was just about reversing the cgaracters, I brought the other constraints from the immediate preceeding exercises.

Comment: @Simon Thank you, but the code works as expected in this state.. it's tinkering with it trying to clean it up that breaks it.

Comment: Sounds like something for Code Understanding (still in Area 51) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding

Comment: Minor: robust code would use `size_t` rather than `int` as an index for an array.  `int` may be too narrow.  Since `size_t` is some unsigned type, code like `i<lim-2` is a problem as `lim-2` may mathematically be less than 0, yet the compare is done with unsigned arithmetic.  To solve such, use `i+2<lim`.

Comment: @chux Interesting, I will look into that as I proceed with practice (I hope I'll remember it at the right moment).

Comment: BTW if youre working K&R exercises why not use their version of getline (chapter 2 or 3??). It seems your version might be having some issues and if so its real easy to stumble into UB.

Comment: @Brandin this code is derived from the version printed in the first chapter, in fact I have only modified it according to the request of the exercises (but I still havan't looked forward in the book).

Comment: If an earlier exercise asks you to modify getline, I would modify it for that exercise but then switch back to the original version for all the exercises going forward. Keep in mind glibc already has its own function called getline, so to avoid conflicts I usually name K&rs version something else like getline2 or something

Comment: @Brandin I think I see your reason. But at the moment I just picked up C this last week and trying to get the gist of what can or can't happen before I evntually start formal lessons next semester.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am getting it, but you are trying to mix up 1.18 and 1.19. By one side, you want to clean the input and, by the other, you are trying to reverse the line. I would suggest you divide what you want to do into different functions. It will not only make it easier to program but also will make it easier to detect errors. This way, I would make one function to get the line and store it into an array, exactly equal to the example given in the book. Then, I would do a second function to clean the lines and a third function which reversed the lines. However, if you want only to solve exercise 1.19, you only need to use the getline and reverse functions. I leave to you the part of writing the main() function.

This way, the getline function:

```
int getline(char line[], int maxsize)
{
    int position, input_character;
    input_character = 0;
    for (position = 0; position < maxsize - 2 && (input_character = getchar()) != EOF && input_character != '\n'; ++position) {
        line[position] = input_character;
    }
    if (input_character == '\n') {
        line[position] = input_character;
        ++position;
    }
    line[position] = '\0';
    return position;
}
```

The clean function:

```
void clean(char output[], char input[]) 
{
    char storage[MAXLINE];
    int output_character, storage_character, input_character;
    output_character = 0;
    storage_character = 0;

    while (output[output_character] != '\0') {                                                  //This goes through output[] until it gets to the last written character
        ++output_character;
    }

    for (input_character = 0; input[input_character] != '\0' && output_character < (MAXCHAR * MAXLINE - 1); ++input_character) {
        if (input[input_character] == ' ' || input[input_character] == '\t') {
            storage[storage_character] = input[input_character];                                //The array storage[] will store me the trailing blanks and tabs
            ++storage_character;
        }
        else if (input[input_character] == '\n') {          //If there is a newline character and nothing has been copied into output, then it is a blank line and is not copied into output
            if (output[output_character] == '\0') {
                ;
            }
            else {
                output[output_character] = input[input_character];                                  //Copy the newline character
                ++output_character;
            }
        }
        else {
            storage[storage_character] = '\0';
            for (storage_character = 0; storage[storage_character] != '\0'; ++storage_character) {
                output[output_character] = storage[storage_character];                              //If there is a character after blanks/tabs, copy storage into output
                ++output_character;
            }
            output[output_character] = input[input_character];                                  //Copy the character
            ++output_character;
            storage_character = 0;
        }
    }
    output[output_character] = '\0';
}
```

And the reverse function:

```
void reverse(char reversed[], char original[])
{
    int size_original, output_char;
    for (size_original = 0; original[size_original + 1] != '\n'; ++size_original) {
        ;
    }
    for (output_char = 0; size_original >= 0; ++output_char) {
        reversed[output_char] = original[size_original];
        --size_original;
    }
    reversed[output_char] = '\n';
    reversed[output_char + 1] = '\0';
}
```

I hope this was useful. Feel free to comment if it didn't help and I will try to answer you.